# Could Lawn Fertiliser kill off slug-control nematodes?

Tags: lawn, pest-control, fertilizer, lawn-repair, nematodes

I use Nemaslug nematodes to control slugs in my garden. I don't normally bother fertilising my lawn but this year its looking a bit sorry for itself so I want to try out some slow release (6 month) fertiliser.

Will this kill off the nematodes and leave me overrun with slugs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [site](http://garden.org/subchannels/care/soil?q=show&id=198&page=3)

> Because of its high nitrogen content, fertilizer can reduce nematode
> effectiveness. Manufacturers recommend that fertilizers not be used
> two weeks prior to and after nematode application. Again, check the
> package instructions.

That being said your mileage may vary depending on soil type, soil temperature and type of fertilizer.  A slow release is definitely the kind to apply.  You could probably achieve similar results by top dressing with organic matter twice a year.

Answer (score 1):

I received an email from BASF who manufacture nemaslug.  It is inline with kevinsky's answer but specifically addresses slow release fertiliser so I thought I would share it.

> A slow release fertiliser should not affect Nemaslug.  It is advisable to wait at least one month after the application of a non-slow release fertiliser, as a high concentration of standard fertilisers can be detrimental to nematodes.